# Where is jetty /context/text.xml?

Tags: java, clojure, jetty

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/ddellacosta/Clojure-under-Jetty-and-Apache#setting-up-jetty-with-apache-httpd) and I am stuck with Jetty configuration. This says that

> Now, change directory to your Jetty install, and to get a working set
>   of default configuration options, just copy the file contexts/test.xml
>   (which comes packaged with Jetty by default) to a new file:

```
$ cp contexts/test.xml contexts/web_test.xml
```

But my jetty install has no `/context` directory:

```
as-MacBook-Air:jetty.home a$ ls
README.TXT
VERSION.txt
bin
demo-base
etc
lib
license-eplv10-aslv20.html
logs
modules
notice.html
resources
start.d
start.ini
start.jar
webapps
```

What am I missing? Where is jetty text.xml file?

Comment: There's a contexts subfolder in that git project which is what the installation guide is referring to, and maybe you're looking at the root directory of the actual Jetty install?

Comment: Yes! You are right. There is a `test.xml` file in `~/jetty.home/demo-base/webapps/test.xml` I will copy that one. Actually there are more than 1 `test.xml` files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Documentation Link: [Configuring a Specific Web Application Deployment](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-specific-webapp-deployment.html)

A "context xml" is any XML file that :

1. Follows the [Jetty IoC XML syntax](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/reference-section.html#jetty-xml-syntax)
2. Configures a [`org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html)
3. And is in a directory that your deployer recognizes

For #2 (Configuring a WebAppContext), an example for Jetty 9 would be

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
   "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/myapp</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps" default="."/>/myapp.war</Set>
  <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>
</Configure>
```

For #3, the deployer directory, that is determined by your own setup and configuration.

See [`etc/jetty-deploy.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-deploy/src/main/config/etc/jetty-deploy.xml) and look for what your `monitoredDirName` is.

- For Jetty 9.1+, that's `${jetty.base}/webapps/`
- For Jetty 8 that's `${jetty.home}/contexts/` see ([`etc/jetty-contexts.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-8.1.14.v20131031/jetty-deploy/src/main/config/etc/jetty-contexts.xml))
- For Jetty 7 that's `${jetty.home}/contexts/` see ([`etc/jetty-contexts.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-7.6.14.v20131031/jetty-deploy/src/main/config/etc/jetty-contexts.xml))

Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 had a quirk in the deployers that was poorly understood, you could deploy a webapp as a WAR via the webapp deployer, or as Context via the context deployer, and if you had both deployers, your webapp would be deployed twice. (confusing endless numbers of people).

With Jetty 9, the 2 deployer techniques were merged to make them aware of each other and prevent duplicate webapp deployment.

**The logic for deployment in Jetty 9 is as follows:**

The webapps directory (aka `monitoredDirName`) is scanned by the [WebAppProvider](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/deploy/providers/WebAppProvider.html).

This provider scans one or more directories (typically "webapps") for contexts to deploy, which may be:

- A standard WAR file (must end in `".war"`)
- A directory containing an expanded WAR file
- A directory containing static content
- An XML descriptor Jetty IoC XML Syntax that configures a ContextHandler or WebAppContext instance

To avoid double deployments and allow flexibility of the content of the scanned directories, the provider implements some heuristics to ignore some files found in the scans:

- Hidden files (starting with `"."`) are ignored
- Directories with names ending in `".d"` are ignored
- If a directory and a WAR file exist ( eg `foo/` and `foo.war`) then the directory is assumed to be the unpacked WAR and only the WAR is deployed (which may reused the unpacked directory)
- If a directory and a matching XML file exist ( eg `foo/` and `foo.xml`) then the directory is assumed to be an unpacked WAR and only the XML is deployed (which may used the directory in it's configuration)
- If a WAR file and a matching XML exist (eg `foo.war` and `foo.xml`) then the WAR is assumed to be configured by the XML and only the XML is deployed.

Comment: So it's still unclear to me. What's the name of **per application** config file where I can specify properties ? `context-param` in `web.xml` is ignored in my case. I'm using Jetty 8.